# why angular app production build's local-server required /index.html to load app

Tags: angular

In the angular app, after running http-server on dist/project_name, why it is required to redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html?
Can I remove this option so that it can behave as like as when i  run it on the dev server?
But when i hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8080/home or something.
also, wild card(**) routes ain't working

my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'shortcut-life',
    loadChildren: () => import('../shortcuts-life/shortcuts-life.module').then(m => m.ShortcutsLifeModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'api-integrations',
    loadChildren: () => import('../api-integrations/api-integrations.module').then(m => m.ApiIntegrationsModule)
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: Show Your `app-routing.module.ts` file ill try to help You with this weard redirect.

Comment: Don't print screen code but copy paste it to post and target code then {} button.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem with code, people who are volunteering to help need the text of the code. Images of the code are not an acceptable substitute. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I will keep it in mind in my next question... thanks, mistakes always teach something new...

Comment: @AshikurRahmanNabir You can `Edit` this question and Rich will see it is correct and he will remove his down vote. If it was he down voted. XD

Answer (score 1):

Angular app is a Single Page Application. It means that when user connect he just need request to `index.html` file. Inside `index.html` file he got more requests that why server need to be set up like if request not fit to any file respond with `index.html` file. Users will want to do requests like `https://yourdomain.com/home` or `/contact` and there is no any file like this so they download `index.html` and then `.js` files. Boundle `.js` files decided what route/page show to user depend on suffix he got in link.

About wild card You need to set it up in `app-routing.module.ts` or where ever You set up routes. Like this: `{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }` remember it have to be last one like in bellow:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RoutesComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'admin', redirectTo: '/admin/users', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuard], children: [
          { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
          { path: 'admins', component: AdminsComponent },
          { path: 'editors', component: EditorsComponent }
        ]
      },
      { path: 'user', component: UserComponent }
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: But when i hit http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html it redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8080/home or something. also, wild card(**) routes ain't working

Comment: It might redirect You becouse of You have set up redirect in Your project ? You need to show app-routing.module.ts file.

Comment: Oh about wild card You need to set it up. If You need and error 404 page not found.

Comment: I set it up, but still not working, see my updated post, I attached a photo

Comment: thanks a lot that u are giving ur precious time, i am learning angular but in prod build i found this problem, i think now u can see my app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Try to run again `ng serve`.

Comment: Oh and if You using `ng build --prod` if You change project You need to build it again. So if You mage some changes keep on rurning on command `ng serve`.